# display twig loop element in bolt

Tags: html, twig, bolt-cms

I would like to create this skeleton with html and twig :

```
group
    actu 1
    actu 2
group
    actu 3
    actu 4
group
    actu 5
    actu 6
```

3 groups with div and 6 differents articles with 2 per group

Curently code

```
{% setcontent actualites = 'actualites' limit 6 %}


<div class="bloc height-30">
    <h3>actualités<a href="./actualites" class="plus"></a></h3>
    <div class="carousel actus-carousel">
        {% for i in 0..2 %}
        <div class="groupe">
                <a href="#" class="actu">
                    <div class="date" style="background:url('h ttps://www.appartcity.com/uploads/media/image_hotel/0001/14/image_hotel_medium/13441_appartement-montpellier-gare-saint-roch-chambre.jpg')">
                        <span>12</span>
                        <span>Nov.</span>
                    </div>
                <h5>{{ actualite.title }}</h5>
                <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam quis risus enean lacinia bibendum nulla sed onsectetur.</p>
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

I display 3 group but I don't know how to show 6 different with 2 per group.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends of the value of actualites but you could probably use the batch filter

```
<div class="wrapper">
  {% for item in actualites|batch(3) %}
    <div class="group">
      {{item.title}}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```